# Storing part of command line arguments into user array

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, array

I am able to do this,

```
array=(2 46 7 4 2 1 1 1 23 4 5)
store=(${array[*]:5:5})
echo ${store[@]}  # print 1 1 1 23 4 5
```

Now instead of extracting the 5 elements from position 5 from a user array, I need to extract **command-line args from 5** and onward. I tried similar way but I am getting empty output

```
store=(${$[*]:5:5})  # <----------------- Something to be changed here?
echo ${store[@]}  # EMPTY OUTPUT
```

Any help, how to store n args from position *mth* onward in a array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bash` (and also `zsh` and `ksh93`, the general form of [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) or `Substring Expansion` is:

```
${parameter:offset:length}
```

If the `length` is omitted, you will get from `offset` to the end of parameter.

In your case:

```
array=(2 46 7 4 2 1 1 1 23 4 5)
store=( "${array[@]:5}" )
printf '%s\n' "${store[@]}"
```

will generate from `6th` element to the last element.

With `$@`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${@:5}"
```

will generate from `$5` to the end of positional arguments.

Also note that you need to quote the array variable to prevent `split+glob` operator on its elements.

---

With `zsh`, you can use another syntax:

```
print -rl -- $argv[5,-1]
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that, I am able to do it for user defined array, but  my question is how do I extract from commandline args i.e $5 to end.

Comment: @mtk: Just using it as-is. Added more details to the answer.